# Getting weird error while writing in java

Tags: java, batch-file

I got a weird error message.. I will show you the code that works..
And the code where I get the error message.

First, the error message:

### Opening the crJAR.bat

```
CatchIt.java:5: error: error while writing CatchIt: CatchIt.class (Zugriff verweigert)
 class CatchIt extends Frame implements KeyListener,Runnable {
 ^
1 error

ERSTELLE RELEASE-DATEI "CatchIt.jar"... bitte warten.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: RELEASE\CatchIt.jar (Zugriff verweigert)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:95)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:192)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1233)
```

This is the code with not a single error:

### crJAR.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
ECHO KOMPILIERE DATEIEN... bitte warten.
javac *.java
ECHO.
ECHO ERSTELLE RELEASE-DATEI "CatchIt.jar"... bitte warten.
jar cvfm RELEASE/CatchIt.jar Manifest.txt *.class
ECHO.
ECHO TEST-START... bitte warten.
java -jar RELEASE/CatchIt.jar
```

BUT... if I remove the last line "java -jar RELEASE/CatchIt.jar", then I get the error.
And I don't get it.. the correlation...

Why isn't it working without that last line?!

Comment: The file `RELEASE\CatchIt.jar` is not found, as the exception telling you.

Comment: Remove the leading slash and see if that fixes it: java -jar RELEASE/CatchIt.jar

Comment: Hey, thanks.. But it is a copyfail. There is no leading slash there.
And the file is existing, there is no readonly on it.